Need to contact deployer 7 to request a return from a mistake transfer
Made a mistake, transferred transaction hash 0x5cbc26214abb61be72e440e4e8ab1d769aa668
6b5fddfcb7cec81067dc9073d2
From:
0x5E22d42FaA7de3958F48A7Ed9A3AD04ca41A
285a
To:
0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B31979
55
Token holder:
0x89150721D07699394Eb6C32f95C927Eca...
789 USDT
By Deployer 7. 0x5E22d42F...ca41A285a
Please return??? I have very little money and made a mistake
Thank you Ron Robertson

Unfortunately, you can't get the assets back, unless you somehow manage to reach the new owner and they agree to return the assets. But it may be very difficult to find the owner.
This is one of the problems / possibilities of blockchains: more responsibility for the users. There is no third party (like a bank or the police) who could help you regain the assets.
